# ASP.Net MVC 5 - Correct way to access HttpContext.Current.User outside of controller?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an  ASP.NEt MVC 5 application which uses a service to access information about the user.

Currently I pass it as a parameter to the method in the service class or do the following in each method where its required:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User;

        // do some stuff
}
```

How can I refactor the code to lets say inject it into the constructor of the class so that its available to any method in the class or is it correct the way i'm doing it at present e.g. passing it as a parameter?

```
public class ViewModelBuilderService : IViewModelBuilderService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;


    public ViewModelBuilderService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork; 

    }

    // Other methods...

}
```

Comment: Check if  `_unitOfWork` is null with a `Get` method, then if it is, call your example method `ViewModelBuilderService` and pass in the user info, else it's already set. Furthermore, you could create this logic as a method inside a base controller which is then inherited by all your other controllers, and call this method on the Index of each controller.

Comment: Not sure about MVC5, but earlier versions would typically set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to the same principal as `HttpContext.Current.User`.  And `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`is what you'd use in the business layer, e.g. by using the `PrincipalPermission` class or `PrincipalPermissionAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why your business layer should at all need to know `HttpContext`. It shouldn't ... in case if at all needed then store the data into a variable and pass it to the method you are calling. Currently the approach you are following.

Probably you can try accessing the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in order to get the authentication context

Comment: @adam78 Yes it is ... definitely

Comment: basically i pass in a parameter `IPrincipal user` to my method becuase i have an IPrincipleExtensions class which returns some permissions e.g. `public static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal user, params string[] roles)  {
 return roles.Any(user.IsInRole); }` The extension class has various other methods too which are needed in the service class.